# Can I use the voice & SMS features of my GSM SIM through my laptop?

Tags: laptop, modem, 3g, voice, gsm

My laptop (a Lenovo T410s) has an internal GSM modem (device manager calls it a Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Modem 9205) that I'm currently using a regular (voice, data, text, etc) 3G SIM in.

The data functionality works great through the Lenovo software & Windows 7 but I was wondering if I can use the other features (specifically voice & SMS) through Windows.

Is it posisble to use the non-data features of my 3G SIM through my Qualcomm GSM modem?  If so, what software is available to this end?  If not, where is the restriction? (e.g. hardware, OS, driver, software)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to get my HP (has a Gobi 2000) to do voice but I did get my Acer 1420p to make calls. It has a Huawei chip in it. Here is how: http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/482532-enabling-ussd-voice-support-em770w-3g-module.html

Answer (score 1):

In India, we have a few operators sell a SIM card with a dongle which you can use to surf the web with your laptop. Some of them have a feature to send texts too. Ask your operator.

Also, if you have a Nokia phone, you can use Nokia PC Suite (free download) to type and send messages from your computer with a Bluetooth, USB or Infrared connection to your phone.

Comment: I have a 'dongle' (Qualcomm Gobi 2000) and I have a SIM that supports SMS & voice.  I'd like to know how I can use the two together.

Comment: If you can, try it.

Well, I suggest you go ask the operator if you can do that.

Comment: I'm positive I can use the features - they work when used in a phone. What I'm asking is *how* to use the voice/SMS features from within Windows.